# Why is the Status Bar STILL showing during Default.png?

Tags: iphone, delegates, statusbar

I'm pretty sure that I've taken all steps to correctly set my status bar to hidden. I did this in both the info.plist file (setting a UIStatusBarHidden to a boolean TRUE) as well as in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method in the Application Delegate using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

And the status bar does hide -- only not quick enough. Despite the steps taken above, when the app is launched, the status bar is STILL being **displayed for about a second** during the displaying of the **Default.png** default image. This looks tacky, and I want to make sure the status bar does not get displayed at any time during the running of the app.

Many apps I've tried **ARE hiding the status bar successfully** (doesn't even show during the display of default.png) but I can't figure out how. Anyone deal with this issue before?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you figure this out already? What I did to get it to work is edit the Info.plist file in TextMate rather than in Xcode. I added the following two lines:

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
```

I think the only thing different from the answers given above is that I used a text editor rather than Xcode. When you subsequently look at Info.plist in Xcode, you will see a check mark next to UIStatusBarHidden rather than a string. There is probably a way to do this directly in Xcode, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Hey. I never solved the issue with the status bar but it seemed to correct itself once I adjusted for / installed 3.0. Now there are no problems.

Comment: The way you set it in Xcode is to open the plist, add the entry, control-click the item in the plist editor, select Value Type -> Boolean in the popup menu, THEN set the value.

Comment: Article on same, goes over everything: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/gotcha-hiding-the-status-bar.html

Answer (score 8):

UIStatusBarHidden should be set to true.

Comment: I am unsure where the downvotes are coming from. There is no need for a compromise, the original poster was very close to the real solution.

As stated in the original question "I did this in both the info.plist file (setting a UIStatusBarHidden to a boolean FALSE)".

All you need to do is set the plist property "UIStatusBarHidden" to TRUE instead of FALSE. That will ensure that the status bar is *always* hidden, even when the Default.png is being shown.

Comment: The downvotes are because your proposed solution has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: Erm - OK so now I'm at fault. Didn't even read your comment thoroughly enough. One vote up from me, it seems like you do actually have a solution. You should've put more info in your answer, saying it needs to be a Info.plist key-value pair.

Comment: Sorry, in my post I listed UIStatusBarHidden as set to FALSE where it is actually TRUE in my info.plist file. You shouldn't have got a downvote -- Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Make sure the plist value is <true/> rather than <string>YES</string>, which I've occasionally encountered causing trouble before.

Answer (score 5):

in the info.plist there's also a key called "Status bar is initially hidden" that needs to be checked on. It will hide the status bar while loading the default.png

Comment: +1 This is the real answer, that allows the status bar to be shown again at some point later in the app.

Answer (score 5):

It's easier than that.  At least in Xcode 4 you can simply add an entry "Status bar is initially hidden" to the plist and set its value to YES.

[image: status bar entry in plist]

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this on Jailbroken devices using IOS 2.1 with an older version of Cydia. In that instance, once Cydia was updated, the info.plist + ...statusBarHidden = YES method worked.

Alternatively see if `[application setStatusBarStyle: ...]` helps.

-isdi-

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing a similar problem on an iPod Touch 2G (3.1.3), where a black rectangle - same dimensions as the status bar - was showing above the default.png.

The solution to this problem involved making the default.png image 320x480 as opposed to its original 640x960. The exact solution was to make a default@2x.png using the larger dimensions.